# Pinescript, separate exit ID for Take Profit and Stop Loss exit criteria

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

There's no problem with exiting my sample reproducible code involving an MA entry and exit by Take Profit (TP or a Stop Loss (SL).

There are two versions here:

1. The commented out conditions at the top exits if either criteria (TP/SL), with an exit ID: "Long Exit Id".
2. This should exit just as above (it's not exiting at all), but with only change that it should register the two type of exits (TP or SL) as separate IDs. I want TP exit's ID as "Long TP Exit Id" & SL exit's ID as "Long SL Exit Id"

Unfortunately, I'm unable to generate the desired outcome! Any tips/insights is welcome.

To make the code reproducible b/w securities/assets, I am fixing the trading instrument as closing price of Gold (which made a new all time high just hours ago!) at a 'daily' frequency. There are some handy aids for plotting!

```
//@version=5
strategy("TP/SLdifferentIDtrial", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

//Parameters
takeProfitF = 0.02
stopLossF = 0.02
fastDayPeriod1 = 5
slowDayPeriod1 = 50

// Figure out take profit price
longExitTakeProfitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeProfitF)

// Figure out  stop loss
longExitStopLossPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopLossF)

// This is only to aid plotting
var strategyBuyBool = false
var strategySellBool = false

AuPricesClose = request.security("GOLD", "1D",close)

fastDayPeriod1SMA = ta.sma(AuPricesClose,fastDayPeriod1)
slowDayPeriod1SMA = ta.sma(AuPricesClose,slowDayPeriod1)

longEntryCondition = ta.crossover(fastDayPeriod1SMA, slowDayPeriod1SMA)
if (longEntryCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long Entry Id", strategy.long, stop = longExitStopLossPrice)
    strategyBuyBool = true // This is for aiding plotting

//longExitCondition = strategy.position_avg_price > 0
// Take Profit and Stop Loss exit if in Long position
//if (longExitCondition)
    //strategy.exit("Long Exit Id", from_entry = "Long Entry Id", limit = longExitTakeProfitPrice, stop = longExitStopLossPrice)

longEntryCondition = ta.crossover(fastDayPeriod1SMA, slowDayPeriod1SMA)
if (longEntryCondition)
    TPcriteria = strategy.position_avg_price >= longExitTakeProfitPrice
    if (TPcriteria)
        strategy.exit("Long TP Exit Id", from_entry = "Long Entry Id", limit = longExitTakeProfitPrice)
    SLcriteria = strategy.position_avg_price <= longExitStopLossPrice
    if (SLcriteria)
        strategy.exit("Long SL Exit Id", from_entry = "Long Entry Id", stop = longExitStopLossPrice)

plot(fastDayPeriod1SMA, color = color.green)
plot(slowDayPeriod1SMA, color = color.red)

plotshape(longEntryCondition, color = color.lime, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(strategyBuyBool, color = color.green, style=shape.arrowup, location=location.belowbar)

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    // Determine the chart type (for label text)
    chartType = timeframe.isintraday ? "intra-day" : "daily or higher"

    // Create the text label
    label.new(x=bar_index + 1, y=close, style=label.style_label_left, 
         size=size.large, color=#ffeecc, textcolor=color.black,
         text="This " + chartType + " chart has\n" + 
             "a bar time frame period of:\n" + timeframe.period +
             " is chart/data daily: " + str.tostring(timeframe.isdaily) )
```